# Replace all code inside div to actual html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace all code inside of a div with actual HTML. The thing is, I don't have access to the core files because I'm doing this on a theme, so I need to do this using javascript/jquery in a way that will convert all the code inside of this specific div.

lets take stackexchange example, when you write code on stackexchange's `about` field and save the changes the code is automatically converted to actual HTML. Although I don't want to literally convert all of the code because this can be a bad thing to do, I just want to convert simple code such as the example below:

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
</ul>
<img src="image.png"/>
<br/>
<strong>strong</strong>

and so on...
```

Comment: if the above all is a string. $(elem).html(string) will replace the html of the div with the string you provided.

Comment: example here http://jsfiddle.net/LjkL6xh5/

Comment: imho this question is unclear, not sure what is expected here?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has [.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/).

However if you're literally converting some text to HTML in the same element you could do:

```
$('#MyDiv').html($('#MyDiv').text());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove all the html content with :

```
$( ".hello" ).empty();
```

And use

```
$( ".hello" ).html("some html")
```

Comment: `$( ".hello" ).html("some html")` would be enough

Comment: the answer before the edit is wrong but some changed it to be a correct one

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#source").appendTo("#destination");
```

or use `insertAfter()` jQuery method.